# java.mail.message.content = null Android

Tags: android, email, imap, pop3

I'm trying get gmail message from Android device but java.mail.message.content always return null, So here's the code:

```
 public void resiveImap(){
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.imap.host" , "imap.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.imap.user" , "**");
  props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory" , 993 );
  props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
  props.put("mail.imap.port" , 993);
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
      @Override
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication( "*" , "*");
              }
  });
  try {
      Store store  = session.getStore("imap");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com" , "*" , "*");
      Folder fldr = store.getFolder("Inbox");
      //fldr.open(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
      int count = fldr.getMessageCount();
      System.out.println(count);
      fldr.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);  

      //4) retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it  
      Message[] messages = fldr.getMessages();  
      for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {  
       Message message = messages[i];  
       System.out.println("---------------------------------");  
       System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));  
       System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());  
       System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);  
       System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString()); 
  }
      } catch(Exception exc) {
      System.out.println(exc + "error");
  }
  }
```

And get exeption on message.getContent() because it's null.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you want to post your password on SO? I hope that is modified.

Comment: I also hoped you changed it, because it is visible in history.